# Adding parameters in middle of URL string in python

Tags: python, url, parameters

url = 'https://api.example.net/api/v2/contactlist/{listId}/deletelist'

#In the above url listId is a parameter I need to pass, how can I achieve this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use string [interpolation](https://peps.python.org/pep-0498/). You have to prefix your string with `f`.

```
listId = 5
url = f'https://api.example.net/api/v2/contactlist/{listId}/deletelist'
```